# Why it display me this on my blog application? ~Ruby on Rails~I don't how to remove a strange thing at the end of the web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to make a simple blog application using Rails.

After I wrote all the code and content I wanted, it displays this at the end:

```
[#<  Post id: 2, title: "Another post", body: "this is the second post", created_at: "2017-11-19 15:02:23", updated_at: "2017-11-19 15:02:23">, #<Post id: 1, title: "First post", body: "lorem ipsum", created_at: "2017-11-19 14:55:58", updated_at: "2017-11-19 14:55:58">]
```

(i made before 2 test posts with titles "First post" and "Another post" and with some random text on body)

And I don't how to remove this.

Here is my "routes.rb" file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root "posts#index"
end
```

"application.html.erb":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Blog</title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="logo">
      <%= link_to root_path do%> 
        <%= image_tag "logo.svg" %> 
      <% end %> 
    </div>

    <ul> 
      <li class="category">Website</li>
      <li><%= link_to "Blog", root_path %></li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li class="category">Social</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/kreker71">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/Kreker71">GitHub</a></li>
      <li><a href="mailto:ursache.codrut71@gmail.com">Gmail</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>

  <%= yield %>
  </body>
  </html>
```

"posts_controller.rb":

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save

    redirect_to @post 
  end

  def show 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private 

  def post_params 
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

"index.html.erb":

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="post_wrapper">
    <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

"new.html.erb":

```
<h1>New Post</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br> 
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%=f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

"show.html.erb":

```
<h1 class="title">
  <%= @post.title %>
</h1>

<p class="date">
  Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
</p>

<p class="body">
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>
```

Comment: Remove the `=` from `<%= @posts.each do |post| %>`, this way you don't print the enumerator itself but only the content within the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `=` from `<%=` on on index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="post_wrapper">
    <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Explanation: The `=` is used to print some thing. So at that line you are printing the `@posts` array which is what you see. Use it only if you need to output some thing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Pleasure is all mine.